# What is one allowed to do during time that one was kavua to learn torah?

Tags: torah-study, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Specifically, I was wondering if the mitzvah of kibbud av va'em is docheh setting aside time for learning torah. For example, if one has set aside time for learning torah and a parent asks their child to do a chore, is one obligated/ allowed to pause one's talmud torah to help their parent?

Comment: Does modern Talmud Torah ever exempt you from a immediate mitzva opportunity?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83292/759

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should Torah study exclude the performance of other mitzvos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/should-torah-study-exclude-the-performance-of-other-mitzvos)

Comment: It definitely sheds some light on my question. However, I am specifically wondering about time that was set aside for torah, not learning torah vs. other mitzvot in general. Talmud Torah and setting aside time for torah are two separate things (I think).